# Pass CSV DataSource from java program to Report's Tables

Tags: java, csv, jasper-reports, datasource

I have a report made of one page which is generated usign a CSV Data Adapter. In the report I have some data and 2 table where both are taking data from CSV file. In a first moment, I had problem with table showing up: I put some data in myTables but nothing were shown. I have been able to solve the problem by using and mapping REPORT_PARAMETER_MAP in ParameterMap table’s section. Now I have the same problem, but calling myReport from a java program. In this last I have created a datasource which I am sending as paramater to the report. As a result, all data are showned, unless the 2 tables.
In Jaspersof Studio I have defined a parameter called DS where its class is: “**new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRCsvDataSource**” and I am passing it to myTables as follow:

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

In java I have:

```
public JasperPrint createReport(InputStream inp) throws SQLException, OutputNotFoundException, OutputEnvelopeCreationException
{
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    try
    {
        String[] columnNames = new String[]{"xxx3", "xxx4", "xxx2", "xxx1"];

        JRCsvDataSource ds = new JRCsvDataSource(inp);
        ds.setFieldDelimiter(';');
        ds.setUseFirstRowAsHeader(true);
        ds.setColumnNames(columnNames);

        _parameters.put("DS", ds);

        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(_jasperReport, _parameters, ds);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        putKOReport(outputStreamEnvelopeFactory,e.toString().getBytes());;
        e.printStackTrace();
        writeErrorLog("OPS: readReportConfiguration " + e.getMessage() + " " + e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return jasperPrint;
}

public void prepareReport() throws SQLException, OutputNotFoundException, OutputEnvelopeCreationException
{
    _parameters.put("PARAM1", "/main/prj/xxx1.png");
    _parameters.put("PARAM2", "/main/prj/xxx2.jpg");
    _parameters.put("PARAM3", "/main/prj/xxx3.jpg");
    _parameters.put("PARAM4", "/main/prj/xxx4.jpg");

    try
    {
        _jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(pathReportJasper);

        writeInfoLog("OPS: Report Configuration "+pathReportJasper+" has been prepared");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        putKOReport(outputStreamEnvelopeFactory,e.toString().getBytes());
        e.printStackTrace();
        writeErrorLog("OPS: prepareReport " + e.getMessage() + " " + e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public byte[] writeOutputFile(JasperPrint jasperPrint)
{
    byte[] reportPdf = null;
    try
    {
        reportPdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        putKOReport(outputStreamEnvelopeFactory,e.toString().getBytes());
        e.printStackTrace();
        writeErrorLog("OPS: writeOutputFile " + e.getMessage() + " " +e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return reportPdf;
}
```

I am doing something wrong? Does anyone could help me, please?

Thank you in adavance!

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the same data source for filling the main dataset and the tables:

```
JRCsvDataSource ds = new JRCsvDataSource(inp);
...
_parameters.put("DS", ds);

jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(_jasperReport, _parameters, ds);
```

This has unpredictable results because of the multiple consumers for the same data source.

If you have control over the `InputStream` source like the path to the file you could pass that as a parameter and construct a new instance of `JRCsvDataSource` for each table that needs it.

Comment: Yes, I am using the same dataset! I already tried to create a new instance of JRCsvDataSource like:                                                                        
      JRCsvDataSource dsTab = new JRCsvDataSource(inp);
...
_parameters.put("DS", dsTab);

jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(_jasperReport, _parameters, ds);                                     but myTable does not appear. I have control of the InputStream. I tried to change the jrDataSource expression and sending the input File, but I get "misplaced quote error..."

Comment: You are still reusing the same `InputStream` that gets consumed in one place. So you cannot reuse it. Paste the File approach to see where you got stuck

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong...I cannot manage the InputStream. By the way, I have been able to solve the problem (I posted the solution)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve the problem: I created a datasource for each table using a cycle from my java program and creating a JRCsvDataSource parameter for each one them. This way all my Tables are getting printed with data. In JRDataSource expression **I had to cast the object $P{DS}** this way:

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRCsvDataSource)$P{DS})
```

otherwise tables were not printed. The object alone does not work!